# pods file with multiple platforms for iOS

Tags: ios, git, cocoapods, podfile

I want to combine 2 pods in my project. One is :

```
source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'DJKFlipper'
```

and the other is:

```
platform :ios, '9.0'
pod 'HQPagerViewController', :git=> 'https://github.com/quangpc/HQPagerViewController.git', :branch=> 'master'
```

The issue is that one is asking for platform 8.0 and other is 9.0

I tried changing the whole file platform to 8.0, but get the following error: `Specs satisfying the HQPagerViewController (from https://github.com/quangpc/HQPagerViewController.git, branch master), HQPagerViewController (= 1.0) dependency were found, but they required a higher minimum deployment target.`

And if keep the target to 9.0, I get above 100 issues in the app after installing pod, as the target platform is incorrect.

I also tried this:

```
target 'Bhaskar' do
  # Comment the next line if you're not using Swift and don't want to use dynamic frameworks

 platform :ios, ‘9.0’
  use_frameworks!

  pod 'HQPagerViewController', :git=> 'https://github.com/quangpc/HQPagerViewController.git', :branch=> 'master'

end

target 'Bhaskar - FlipView’ do
  source 'https://github.com/CocoaPods/Specs.git'
platform :ios, '8.0'
use_frameworks!

pod 'DJKFlipper'
end
```

but getting an error here too. I have used pods maybe for the second time ever, and always worked with same platform. How can I combine these both?

Any help will be appreciated!
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It's because your 'Deployment Target' in your project settings is lower than 9.0 (which is the minimum required by HQPagerViewController), so you'd have to change that to 9.0. [image]

Comment: But the platform for 1 pod is 8.0 and for the other is 9.0

Answer (score 0):

Since you have a minimum requirement of ios 9 for one pod your target platform should be 9. You could change the deployment target as mentioned by RJiryes above.  Since one of your pods is base 8, in most cases it should support ios 9 to. But in case your ios 8 pod has deprecated code from ios 9, in that case you will have to pork your pod and change it to support ios9. And It is important that you use up to date pods as using older version of pods are not good practice and may end up having issues.